# Jquery Mobile on() function does not work as a replace to my live function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Its probabaly a very old problem I am trying to replace a pop up which is written in jquery mobile 1.0.1 , and jquery 1.6.4. I am currently trying to use jquery mobile 1.3.2 and jquery 1.9.1.

The piece of code I am struggling with changing is as follows

```
  $("select[id='action_menu']").live("change",actionHandler);
```

to this

$(document).on('click', "(select[id='action_menu'])", actionHandler );

or if anyone has a better suggestion also the look and feel of the  pop has changed a lot from  the older version.

link to Fiddle with all the js and css files 
http://jsfiddle.net/hgafoor/85qy3/

Comment: Look at the colors in your question, and notice what a mess you've made with those quotes !

Comment: @adeneo I tried putting a bunch of alert in the actionHandler function, none of them get displayed when I use "(select[id='action_menu')" although when I tried using '#action_menu-menu' it was going to the alerts in actionHandler. I am pretty new to jquery and have looked at different options like bind,delegate but none of them work

Comment: Why do you have parentheses in your `select[id='action_menu']` selector? That's not a valid selector, which is likely causing your code to fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it worked for me, fairly clean and simple credits to Omar for being such a great help.

```
 $("select").on("change", function () { 
   if ($(this).val() == 'home') { 
   window.location.href = 'google.com'; 
   } else { 
  window.location.href = 'mail.google.com'; 
  } 
  });
```

Comment: This doesn't replicate the original `live` functionality, though, does it? When this code runs, it will attach listeners to all `select` elements already on the page, but it will not cause the listener to attach to `select` elements added later on.

Comment: it works fine for me, most of the documentation I could find tell you to replace it with an .on I haven't used .live enough to actually know the difference though...probably someone who's been working on JQM for a while might have a better answer to your question. I assume that this should work on any "select" ...would adding it inside a .ready() or mobileinit() make it work all the time?

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your quotes:

```
$(document).on('click', "(select[id='action_menu'])", actionHandler );
```